# Weird $user variable confusion between drupal 6 and ubercart

Tags: drupal-6

I've set up a hook alter that adds a submit function to a webform submit chain. In that function alongside some other processing I add:

```
function webform_checkout_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'webformSubmitAlteration';   
}
function webformSubmitAlteration(&$form, &$form_state) {
    global $user;
    $user->last_submission = $sids[1];
    drupal_set_message('<pre> current user is: '. check_plain(print_r($user, TRUE)) .'</pre>');
}
```

That function also redirects to the ubercart checkout page.

The printed $user shows as (edited for clarity):

```
 current user is: stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 1
    [name] => paul.dambra
    [last_submission] => 85
)
```

I then process the cart through checkout which fires an ubercart conditional action that runs some custom php. Basically when this payment completion is caught I want to use the last_submission value to switch the submitted form from draft to complete so that my users now which applications are done and dusted.

In that code I have added:

```
global $user; 
drupal_set_message('<pre> user is : '. check_plain(print_r($user, TRUE)) .'</pre>');
$sid = $user->last_submission;
drupal_set_message('<pre> sid is : '. check_plain(print_r($sid, TRUE)) .'</pre>');
```

And when we see the output of those drupal_set_message calls:

```
user is : stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 1
    [name] => paul.dambra
    [last_submission] => 47
)
```

I know that 47 is the last_submission value from prior to processing the form in question. So even though when I submit the form I can see the correct value for last_submission when I immediately afterwards process the cart I see an old value.

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong would be super!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit my code to:

```
    global $user;
    if ($user) {
      $array = array('last_submission' => $sids[1]);
      user_save($user, $array);       
    }
```

It now works as I expect. Hope that helps someone else...